# can't find .so library -l in makefile

Tags: c++, c, makefile, shared-libraries, dynamic-library

I am new to makefiles, I want to make an .so library and use it in main.o file, I want to use the library from the current directory. how can I make this works?

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -g
CC = g++

all: main.o mylib.so
    $(CC) main.o mylib.so -o runProg

mylib.so : b1.o a1.o head1.h header2.h header3.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared -fPIC -o mylib.so b1.o a1.o

b1.o: b1.cc b1.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fPIC b1.cc

a1.o: a1.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fPIC a1.cc

main.o: main.cc 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cc -L. -lmylib
```

error i am getting:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmylib
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:28: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

any help and correction to make this work is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

So a few things wrong. When you are using `$(CC)` for compilation only, you must specify `-c`. So

```
b1.o: b1.cc b1.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -fPIC b1.cc

a1.o: a1.cc
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -fPIC a1.cc
```

Going from main.cc to main.o is a compilation step, so doesn't need the shared library (but does need the `-c` option). So

```
main.o: main.cc 
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) main.cc
```

The program linking step does need the library options and should mention the file being produced (rather than `all`). So

```
runProg: main.o mylib.so
    $(CC) main.o -o runProg -L. -lmylib
```

Haven't checked anything, but hopefully that helps. No doubt if anything is wrong it will be corrected.

Comment: Thanka a lot! I updated my code, I am getting this one after updates:  ```mylib.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized``` referring to the line of ```$(CC) main.o mylib.so -o runProg -L. -lmylib```

Comment: Not sure, is your library really called `mylib.so`?

Comment: You should not add `mylib.so` to the link line: you have `-lmylib` which is what you need.  Also, if you want to use `-lmylib` then your shared library  must be prefixed by `lib`: e.g., it should be named `libmylib.so`.

Comment: @MadScientist Yes, but I wasn't sure if mylib.so was the real library name, or just a made up name for this question.

Comment: I am a starter to libraries, is the name of the library is same as the files which have the functions? because for the ```mylib.so``` I thought that it is a name we give for the library as target. I don't have any file named like that but about 2 (.cc) and 3 header files which all together should be part of the library

Comment: @Mar As Mad Scientist said there was a mistake in my linking line, I've fixed it now.

Comment: @Mar When you use `-lsomething`, the linker will look for a library called `libsomething.so`. So it's convenient to prefix your library names with `lib`. So call it `libmylib.so` if you wish.

Comment: The library name should start with `lib`, any reference to that library in the makefile should use the full name of the library `libxxx.so` except the `-l` option which should drop the `lib` prefix and the `.so` suffix, i.e. `-lxxx`. Make sense?

Comment: @john yes thanks! i changed it and the error is gone! but got another one for the lines of the libmylib.so target. is the way I am passing files right in this line 
``` $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared -fPIC -o mylib.so b1.o a1.o head1.h header2.h header3.h```

Comment: I don't think you should mention the header files in the linking command, I;ve fixed that above as well.

Comment: ```makefile:22: recipe for target 'libmylib.so' failed
mingw32-make: *** [libmylib.so] Error 1```

Comment: There should be a more specific error before that. That error just tells you that the command failed for some reason.

Comment: @john if I have multiple header files that have functions inside them, and also multiple cpp files and they are all part of my library, then where should i link them? because without the library the makefile is running well, but in the way i added the ```libmylib.so``` rule i am getting many errors i guess because of the linking in makefile.

Comment: You only need to link the cpp files (strictly speaking you need to link the .o file produced from the .cpp file). If there is code in the header file that needs to be included in your main program, then the main program should #include those header files. Header files may describe a library, but they are never part of the library as such. And when you distribute a library you distribute the .so file and the header files together.